# OpenLayers 3 popup not showing information on map

Tags: openlayers-3

Question about js, openlayers3 plugin ol3-popup. For some reason single click method that is used on map element to launch popup element behaves erratic. Some times it displays data correctly and some times it does not. The premise is simple i have points on a map that are described by GeoJSON. Every point is visible in a sevrice and passed in gjlayer. For some reason sometimes when I click on a point it shows a popup with all the data and some times it does not.

I traced a code line by line and main suspect is a:

---

```
var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel, function(feature, layer)   {
            console.log('Entered forEachFeature');
            console.log(feature);
            console.log(layer);
            //temp = feature;
            return feature;
        });
```

---

function. For some reason it can not detect feature that is clicked on.
This is a full code that i tried.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var map = new ol.Map({
    target: 'map',
    renderer:'canvas',
    view: new ol.View({
        center: [1779318.3729059827, 5750751.626054873],
        zoom: 3
        })
    });

    var point_style = new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Circle({
            radius: 5,
            fill: new ol.style.Fill({
                color: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)',
                opacity: 0.8
            }),
            stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                color: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.9)',
                opacity: 0.8,
                width: 3
            })
        })
    });
    var gJSONFeatures = new ol.source.GeoJSON({
        projection: map.getView().getProjection(),
        url: 'some geojson service'
    });
    var gjlayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        title: 'Geojson points',
        source: gJSONFeatures,
        style: point_style
    });
    var baseLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
        useInterimTilesOnError: true,
        title: 'OSM Map',
        source: new ol.source.XYZ({
            url: 'xyz tile server',
            crossOrigin: null,
            attributions: [
                        new ol.Attribution({
                            html: 'misc data'
                        })
                    ]
           })
    });
    var baseGroups = new ol.layer.Group({
        title: 'Base Layers',
        layers: [baseLayer]
    });
    var overlayGroups = new ol.layer.Group({
        title: 'Overlay',
        layers: [gjlayer]
    });
    map.addLayer(baseGroups);
    map.addLayer(overlayGroups);
    var myScaleLine = new ol.control.ScaleLine();
    map.addControl(myScaleLine);
    var myFullScreenControl = new ol.control.FullScreen();
    map.addControl(myFullScreenControl);
    var layerSwitcher = new ol.control.LayerSwitcher({
        tipLabel: 'Legende' // Optional label for button
    });
    map.addControl(layerSwitcher);
    var popup = new ol.Overlay.Popup();
    map.addOverlay(popup);
    map.on('singleclick', function(evt) {
        //registered single click
        // Hide existing popup and reset it's offset
        console.log('Single clck works');
        console.log(evt);
        popup.hide();
        popup.setOffset([0, 0]);
        // Attempt to find a feature in one of the visible vector layers
        var feature = map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(evt.pixel,     function(feature, layer) {
            console.log('Entered forEachFeature');
            console.log(feature);
            console.log(layer);
            //temp = feature;
            return feature;
        });
        if (feature) {
            var coord = feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates();
            var props = feature.getProperties();
            console.log(props);
            var info = "<h2>"+props.name+"</h2>";
            info += "<p>Lon/Lat: " + props.position + "</p>";
            info += "<p>Phone: " + props.phone + " Time: " + props.time + "</p>";
            info += "<p>Speed: " + props.speed.toString() + "</p>";
            // Offset the popup so it points at the middle of the marker not the tip
            popup.setOffset([0, -22]);
            popup.show(coord, info);
        } else {
            console.log('No feature.');
        }
    });
    var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({});
    var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
        // New unnamed vector layer used to display points that are     `enter code here`//agregated by websocket.
        source: vectorSource,
        style: point_style
    });
    map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
    function positioningUpdate() {
           // web socket logic implemented and working
    };
    positioningUpdate();
</script>
```

Libraries used are:

```
OpenLayers 3.3.0
ol3-popup for version 3.3.0
ol3-layers used for openlayers 3.3.0
jquery-1.11.0.min.js
jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js
bootstrap.min.js
```

Do you by any chance have some advice how to resolve current situation?

Comment: I am having a similar problem. ol.source.GeoJSON does not have a "getClosestFeatureToCoordinate" method, which is a method of ol.source.Vector().

Are you finding sometimes the popup that is created by a feature in your ol.source.Vector feature set, is done correctly, while the popup created by the ol.source.GeoJSON isn't?